# C# Windows Form HttpClient cURL

Tags: c#, json, curl, post

I need an example of sending a POST request to the server and getting a JSON response.

Problem in sending image.

I have a curl:

```
curl -k -v -X POST 
-H "X-Auth-Token: 123" 
-H "Content-Type: image / jpeg" 
--data-binary @ Face_foto.jpg http: // IP: port / 1 / storage / descriptors? estimate_attributes = 1.
```

How to implement it in C #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", "123");
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\somepath\somefile.jpg"))
{
    using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
    {
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        var result = client.PostAsync("https://www.someuri.com", content).Result;
    }  
}
```

I wrote this in a hurry so watch out for issues with `PostAsync` and the `File.OpenRead` method.

Comment: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg"); I have an error in this line: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Incorrect header name. Ensure that request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects. '

Comment: Oh yes, I updated the code sample. Add the header to the `content` object instead (see above).